# Trying to Upload file

Tags: vb.net, soundcloud

To whom it may concern,

I have a program that records sounds (*.wav(s) converted to *.wma(s) and *.m4a(s)) that I’m trying to upload to SoundCloud (previously the program had burned CD’s of the WMP Playlists and then I added a section that made a *.zip of the Playlist and attached it to an email), now my users want to upload the WMP playlists to their SoundCloud accounts.

I’ve already added a routine to upload the *.zip file to Dropbox and that works fine. Since the oauth2 for Dropbox was very similar to the oauth2 for SoundCloud, I was able to add my App to the SoundCloud list of Apps, and then add a browser control to my program for the user to “allow” my App to “link” to their SoundCloud account (very similar to how Dropbox handles it).
So I’m up to the point of uploading, but this is handled very differently and I’m having a hard time trying to get this to work (find the right HTTP handlers in Visual Basic to do what I need to do).

In my Dropbox section, I simply had to create a POST message, with the Title of the file and the oauth2 access_token in the URL, then I simply out to read the *.zip file (or any file that I was going to upload) and Write its contents to the GetRequestStream. The only stumbling block that I had was the “Content-Type” which had to be “application/zip” or whatever extension the file was and voila, It was uploaded.

I’ve been reading about multi-part forms and I’m getting a little confused (again the mechanics of the HTTP structures in Visual Basic can be a bit different…duh!...then in other languages…but I’ll try and explain).

I came across one example that used another constructor. Rather than the **HttpRequest** that I had used to build my “request” and “response” communications, this one had a WebClient. The **WebClient** could add Headers (Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Content-Type, Content-Disposition), and also a QueryString (this is where I placed the oath_token, track[asset-data], track[title], etc). Finally, the WebClient constructor had a WebClient.UploadFile command (which took the URL and the physical filename…which I believed would then handle the writing of the file contents the Request).

So…after getting through some 400’s, 401’s (have to deal with expiring token stuff), 422’s, a 503, and a bunch of 500’s (which is where I’m currently at), I still can’t upload a simple *.wma file: *Track001.wma*.

> Here’s my code (strFileName is already built with the physical name of
>   the sound file \|dir|\Track001.wma, and strAccessToken was already
>   obtained from SoundCloud):

```
strURL = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?oauth_token=" & strAccessToken
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3")
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6")
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=track[title]")
```

> I  also tried this line as well:

```
 myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strFileName))
```

> This adds the SoundCloud params

```
Dim myQueryStringCollection As New NameValueCollection()
myQueryStringCollection.Add("oauth_token", strAccessToken)
myQueryStringCollection.Add("track[asset_data]", strFileName)
myQueryStringCollection.Add("track[title]", "Test Track Upload")
myQueryStringCollection.Add("track[sharing]", "public")
myQueryStringCollection.Add("track[downloadable]", "true")
myQueryStringCollection.Add("track[post_to]", "")
```

> This attaches the params into the Request

```
myWebClient.QueryString = myQueryStringCollection
```

> Here’s where I try and send it

```
Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadFile(strURL, strFileName)
```

> But I’m receiving an error here: **{"errors":[{"error_message":"422 -
>   Unprocessable Entity"}]}**
>   If I set the Content-type to multi-form, I
>   get: **The Content-Type header cannot be set to a multipart type for
>   this request**

I just tried to get a 500 again, but all I’m getting now is the 422 (so maybe it’s fixed on the other end?).

Comment: Use Fiddler2 & upload the same file from your program & via your web browser & then compare the sessions for differences or if you cant see them post up the Raw headers here / message me with them & I can check, there is also a compare option in Fiddler which is very helpful.